# apt-get update error!

Tags: 16.04, apt, wireless, package-management, realtek

I am a new ubuntu use. please help me out here.

```
apt-get update
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu:  `apt-get` needs root or admin privileges; so you need to `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Do not realy know if it helps:

Permission problem: you must do the `apt` operations as root or sudoer ie.: 
- log in as root (dangerous)
- became a sudoer and then you can write the command this way:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Another problem with similar error/warnings: you cannot do `apt` operations simultaneously = check if you have some other `apt` process running - in another console may run `aptitude`, in Xwindows runs `Synaptics`. The other processes do lock the necessary libs, package-lists etc.

Good luck